# How do Wordpress Plugins Update Themselves?

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I am quite curious how people go about updating wordpress plugins. I have seen in the past a link to click on the dashboard to update a plugin. What goes on behinds the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just downloads the latest package from the wordpress.org or the developers site and extracts it into the existing folder, which is why you should not edit plugin files because your work will be erased if you ever update.

Comment: When we update a plugging is there any modifications in database ?